# Remove unnecessary space above and below text coming from line Height dynamically

Tags: css, text, spacing, typography

I've built a style guide with text classes and helper spacing classes. Recently for a feature the developer pointed out that additional spacing is being added above and below the text block based on the line height of the class (**even if there was only 1 line of text**), and this is creating inconsistencies in the design.

I've looked around and still can't find a solution to overcome this. As the product i'm working on is a dynamic platform and static css fix on a case by case basis will not work. How can I solve this problem?

```css
large {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: -10px;/*this doesn't work*/
}
medium {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: -10px;/*this doesn't work*/
}
```

```html
<div style="color:#0000FF; padding-top:20px;">
<large>BIG</br>TEXT</large>
<medium>BIG</br>TEXT</medium>
</div>
```

if you look at the above example based on the line height there is also an additional spacing that's 1/2 of the line height above and below the text. how can i stop this from happening

Comment: It will be down to guesswork on our part without some kind of example. We need an example of your text and spacer classes with some HTML as context on how they will be used. You are best off providing a snippet, use the <> button in the question editor.

Comment: 99% of questions posted are required to have a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for,

what I did here is decrease line height so it will remove unnecessary space above and below from text and increase space in between text with stylized `<br>` tag

```css
br {
  content: "";
  margin: 2em;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10%;
}

large {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  line-height: 35px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

medium {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  line-height: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="color:#0000FF; padding-top:20px;">
  <large>BIG<br/>TEXT</large>
  <medium>BIG<br/>TEXT</medium>
</div>
```

hope it helps